# После удаления из коллекции List он все равно каким то образом попадает в HashMap

Tags: java

Есть метод, который удаляет планету из List:

*

```
**public List<Planet> destroyPlanet(Planet planet) {
        if (planetList.contains(planet)) {
            planetList.remove(planet);
            System.out.println("Планета " + planet.getPlanetName() + " уничтожена");
            return planetList;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Планета " + planet.getPlanetName() + " не найдена");
            return planetList;
        }
    }**
```

- 

Но после этого эта планета все равно почему- добавляется в Мар:

```
public HashMap<Planet, Lord> addPlanetToLord(Planet planet, Lord lord) {
        if (lordAndPlanets.containsKey(planet)) {
            System.out.println("У планеты " + planet.getPlanetName() + " есть повелитель");
            return lordAndPlanets;
        } else {
            lordAndPlanets.put(planet, lord);
            System.out.println("Планета " + planet.getPlanetName() + " передана поелителю " + lord.getLordName());
            return lordAndPlanets;
        }
    }
```

Каким образом HashMap все равно добавляет удаленную планету!?
https://github.com/butr1m/nti.team.git
По проекту есть еще вопросы, если кто-то согласится ответить, буду благодарен!

Comment: "Каким образом HashMap все равно добавляет удаленную планету!?" - таким образом, что Вы ее передаете в `addPlanetToLord`.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `destroyPlanet` просто удаляет экземпляр объекта `planet` из списка.   Сам объект `planet` не удаляется. Дальше, в вашем варианте метод `addPlanetToLord` просто добавляет этот экземпляр планеты в `Map`.

Comment: как тогда  мне удалить его?

Answer (score 0):

[Код в репозитории](https://github.com/butr1m/nti.team/blob/master/src/service/LordService.java#L26-L36) несколько отличается, но он должен сначала проверить, существует ли планета, то есть, содержится ли она в списке, который возвращается из `PlanetService`, и только тогда проверять, есть ли у неё хозяин:

```java
public HashMap<Planet, Lord> addPlanetToLord(Planet planet, Lord lord) {
    if (!planetService.getPlanetList().contains(planet)) {
        System.out.println("Планета " + planet.getPlanetName() + " не существует!");
    } else if (lordAndPlanets.containsKey(planet)) {
        System.out.println("Планета " + planet.getPlanetName() + " уже принадлежит повелителю " + lord.getLordName());
    } else {
        lordAndPlanets.put(planet, lord);
        System.out.println("Планета " + planet.getPlanetName() + " передана повелителю " + lord.getLordName());
    }
    return lordAndPlanets;
}
```

Comment: я пытался так делать
проблема в том, что когда я вызываю на planetService. getPlanetLIst, то у меня вылетает NullPointerException:


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "service.PlanetService.getPlanetList()" because "this.planetService" is null
 at service.LordService.addPlanetToLord(LordService.java:28)
 at Test.main(Test.java:50)

Comment: А что мешает в классе `Test` проинициализировать свойство `planetService` экземпляра класса `LordService` после создания обоих сервисов?  `lordService.setPlanetService(planetService);`

Comment: отсутствие знаний, недостаток опыта)
спасибо)

Comment: А. бывает, ничего страшного, с годами пройдёт